# Explicitly defining the end of the input in a regular expression using $

Tags: java, regex

I have this code using a regular expression to separate an input string into two words, where the second word is optional (I know that I might use `String.split()` in this particular case, but the actual regular expression is a bit more complex):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Dollar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*(?: (.*))?$");   // Works
        //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*(?: (.*))?");    // Does not work

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("first second");
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println("first : " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("second: " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

With this code, I get the expected output

```
first : first
second: second
```

and it also works if the second word is not there.

However, if I use the other regexp (without the dollar sign at then end), I get empty strings / nulls for the capture groups.

My question is: Why do I have to explicitly put a **dollar sign** at the end of the regexp to match the "the end of the input sequence" (as the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) says)? In other words, why is the end of the regular expression not implicitly treated as the end of the input sequence?

Comment: @chiastic-security Essentially yes - I can not remember that I had to put the "$" at the end before, especially when there was only a single line of input, so I am wondering what makes this regexp somewhat "special"

Comment: The pattern which doesn't work is looking for some stuff followed by a colon and a space, followed by _zero_ or more characters.  You are using a non-greedy match, so `sometext: ` matches.  Putting in the dollar forces a match with some stuff followed by a colon and a space, followed by _zero_ or more characters, followed by the end of the line.

Comment: As @anubhava said, the non-greedy `*` yields the minimum matching sequence, which yields empty sequences if you don't 'force' the expression to consider *all* characters up to the end of the input with `$`.

Comment: @Tony The expression is not looking for `:`. `(?:X)` is a "non-capturing group" matching only `X`. See "Special constructs" in the JavaDoc.

Comment: @HannoBinder Agreed.  Does it serve any useful purpose in this example to have the non-capturing group?  Would it make any difference to use: `(.*?)\\s* (.*)?$` ?

Comment: Yes, it would make a difference: This expression makes the single space mandatory. The original expression groups the space and subsequent characters and makes this whole group optional, so there's no single space required. Indeed, I think `(?: (.+))?` (note the `+` instead of `*`) is actually closer to what the OP intended because otherwise a single trailing space would be matched too, while he's actually looking for a space followed by a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to lazy nature of your regex which finds & captures many empty matches.

If you use this better regex:

```
(\S+)(?: (.*))?
```

Then it will also work with:

```
(\S+)(?: (.*))?$
```